# how can i sort my array using (shifting to right)

Tags: arrays, sorting, object, shift

ihave to read from file and add student name and id to array of object,after i 
added it i want sort indexs (information by id)
and this is the input example

100
       ADD 123 aa bb 
ADD 899 cc dd 
ADD 222 ff gg 
ADD 565 ii hh 
ADD 777 kk oo
QUIT

```
    int maxNumStudents = read.nextInt();
    Student[] arrayObStudent = new Student[maxNumStudents];
    while (read.hasNext()) {
        do {
            command = read.next();

            switch (command) {
                case "ADD":

                    arrayObStudent[Student.getNumStudents()] = new Student();
                    arrayObStudent[Student.getNumStudents()].setID(read.nextInt());
                    arrayObStudent[Student.getNumStudents()].setFname(read.next());
                    arrayObStudent[Student.getNumStudents()].setlName(read.next());
```

//this will print it without sort                       System.out.println(arrayObStudent[Student.getNumStudents()].getID() + "\n");
                        System.out.println(arrayObStudent[Student.getNumStudents()].getFname());
                        System.out.println(arrayObStudent[Student.getNumStudents()].getlName());
                        Student.increseStudents(1);
etc..

Comment: What do you mean "shifting to right"? What format is your input data? Consider using universal file types such as csv, json, xml, or something similar.

Comment: Why does Student have a function `getNumStudents()`?

Comment: I'm using java, my input file is txt , shifting to right means the index of the array I'm trying to shift it because I want to insert in the blank index the sorted id from 1-8 example and getNumStudents()  is for to know which student index are you

Comment: .txt extension is just a text document which can contain anything. You should use accepted data types such as json, xml, csv, or something similar. Also, you should not store the index inside an object. index should be stored at the collection level.

Answer (score 0):

On every insert you can check the correct position in the array to insert the student.
That's how the array will remain sorted.

```
int insertStudent (int arrayObStudent[], int firstStudentId, int lastStudentId, Student target)
{
  int i = lastStudentId;  
  while ((i > firstStudentId) && (target.getID() < arrayObStudent[i-1]))
    {   
      arrayObStudent[i] = arrayObStudent[i-1];
      i = i - 1;
    }
  arrayObStudent[i] = target; 
  return i;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried Your code but, in this line I got an error (Student cannot converted into int) 
           arrayObStudent[i] = target;

Comment: The arrayObStudent passed to the function is of type 'int' just changed it to Student type it will work..

int insertStudent (Student arrayObStudent[], int firstStudentId, int lastStudentId, Student target)
{
  int i = lastStudentId;  
  while ((i > firstStudentId) && (target.getID() < (arrayObStudent[i-1]).getID()))
    {   
      arrayObStudent[i] = arrayObStudent[i-1];
      i = i - 1;
    }
  arrayObStudent[i] = target; 
  return i;
}

Comment: another error in this line while ((i > firstStudentId) && (target.getID() < arrayObStudent[i-1]))   ( bad operand types first type int secound student)

Comment: it's good without error sorry for asking where can I put the method exactly to work and when i call it what parameters should i write in

Comment: 1. Please changed the code according to your class structure to get rid of errors.
2. You need to store the previously entered studentId and pass it as parameter for lastStudentId.
3. I would suggest you to use ArrayList for storing students rather than an array. It will be easier.